# Scrollorama glitch when scrolling to the top

Tags: jquery

http://europeanbob.co.uk/new/about.html

I'm using 3d transforms to create faux-cubes which drop down into place when scrolling down, but if you scroll up too fast they don't return to beyond the top of the page. Is there anyway to fix this?

Thanks in advance!